# GruntJS usemin doesn't look in subfolders

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using grunt and usemin with my angularjs project. Specifically my issue is concerned with `usemin` not revving image tags in any *.html file within a subdirectory of views.

My .html files are in the following structure

```
dist/
    index.html
    views/
        profile.html
        partials/
            header.html
            ...
```

The `grunt usemin:html` task is processing everything in views/ but not within any of it's subfolders. ie. partials/*

Here is my grunt config:

```
...
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }
},
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
  }
},
...
```

### What I've Tried

I tried adding these options to my `usemin` config:

```
options: {
    basedir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
    dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*']
}
```

But still it doesn't process any subfolder of views.

### Update

Thanks to jakerella's answer noa's comment I got the following to work:

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
  }
},
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're close, but I think you'll want to use the `**` glob pattern in the `html` target of the `usemin` task:

```
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
    ...
}
```

And you might need an `expand: true` in there as well (but not sure if the `usemin` task uses that option).

Comment: Thanks just trying this now. Seems to be processing everything in the ```dist``` folder. ie. things within my ```components``` directory as well. Can this be changed to be anything within ```views```?

Comment: Actually I'd need just index.html of ```dist``` and then everything within ```dist/views```

Comment: Sure, just put multiple quoted patterns in that `html` array.